# LB for multiple Ngnix ingress controllers in private AKS

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, kubernetes-service, azure-load-balancer

I have a private AKS cluster, which is running an NGINX ingress controller that has multiple replicas for HA.
I would like to put a proxy/LB in front of NGINX ingress controller in order to have only one endpoint for end users. What my options are in this case?
I was thinking about having k8s service to proxy multiple ingress controllers.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to put a proxy/LB in front of NGINX ingress controller in
> order to have only one endpoint for end users.

If your service type `Loadbalancer`, **LB** is already there in front of the `Nginx ingress controller`.

Still, if you are looking forward to setting the Another Proxy Or LB

> I was thinking about having k8s service to proxy multiple ingress
> controllers.

You can try the `ISTIO service mesh` which will provide you the **sidecar** container proxy if you want multiple proxy setup.

Ref : https://istio.io/latest/blog/2019/data-plane-setup/

Either if you want to use the `Nginx ingress controller`, you can set up another Ingress controller, `API gateway, service mesh` in front of `Nginx ingress controller.

So your flow will go like :

```
API gateway/ingress controller/service mesh ----> Nginx ingress controller ---> k8s service --> Deployment PODs
```

it might get changes little if you plan to use the sidecar proxy with service mesh.